# How to access a value from JSON object returned by Google Api(userinfo) in Java

Tags: java, json, jsp, jakarta-ee, oauth

I want to access just the email address and name from the JSON returned by Google API. Below is a snippet of my code. jsonIdentity returns the entire Json

String USER_INFO_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo";

```
public String getUserInfoJson(final String authCode) throws IOException {
    final GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(authCode).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    final Credential credential = flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
    final HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(credential);
    final GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(USER_INFO_URL);
    final HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
    request.getHeaders().setContentType("application/json");
    final String jsonIdentity = request.execute().parseAsString();
    return jsonIdentity;

}
```

Comment: The below links defines how you can read the json in java. http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example

Answer (score 0):

add maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
```

and use:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonIdentity);
String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Google API, you may want to consider using the [Google-GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/README.md) library to parse the JSON.

The basic use of Google-GSON goes as such:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); // This object is reusable so I'd cache it rather than keep recreating it.
DataObject d = gson.fromJson(jsonString, DataObject.class);
```

[View the User Guide for more information.](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)